# Prevent arm from twisting when moving it foward

Tags: rigging

What type of constraint would I use to fix this?
I've tried limiting rotation but it didn't seem to do anything

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JZBML1q.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/iGob0AW.gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Properties editor ‣ Bone there is a special section named Inverse Kinematics. You could adjust this on the bone you want to fix instead of adding a constraint.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/rigging/armatures/posing/bone_constraints/inverse_kinematics/introduction.html

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/X6dW0g1.png I currently have inverse kinematics in the wrist area and a pole joint to prevent his elbow from bending the wrong way. If it needs another, what joint would I put it in to fix this problem?

Comment: Scratch that, the pole joint was actually what caused the problem in the first place.